# Google app engine to run Shell Script files

Tags: shell, file, google-app-engine, whitelist, app-engine-flexible

Is it possible to run Shell Script files in google app engine? Like by using

`Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xxx/xxx/xxx/kishan.sh "); //Whatever you want to execute?`

There is whitelist on google app engine documentation which lists classes that can be used but functions/ inside the classes are not specified.
 I am Trying Using Java

Answer (score 2):

On GAE-Standard, you cannot call shell scripts.  On GAE-Flexible, you can. [Read more about GAE-Standard vs GAE-Flexible environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).

Comment: Thanks, @BareNakedCoder I know that but I am not getting any sample how to build.To do Show First i have to write my script on Docker instance after that i need to execute if its right then i will try and if i am wrong then how can i do.

Answer (score 2):

Try GAE Flex custom runtime, you can build your own Docker image locally, test it and then deploy it. It will need an app.yaml file like

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```